# How to call function by given pointer using raw data (bytes) on runtime (instead of casting to compile-time defined function) in C/C++

Tags: c++

Imagine we have an untyped raw function pointer

```
void * my_func = ...; // get from DLL for example
```

How to call my_func with specif data (and get return value), if the size of all parameters together and the size of return type could be known only on the runtime.

For example I need to implement the following interface:

```
void call_func(void * func, size_t return_type_size, size_t parameters_size, void * return_data, void * parameters_data){

    // 1. put data from parameters_data onto the stack frame
    // 2. call func
    // 3. put data from function call into return_data
}
```

so if we have a function like `double my_double_func(int a, char b)`
the usage of call_func will be the following

```
// get from DLL for example
void * my_func = <recived on runtime>; 

// with my_double_func should be sizeof(double) = 8
size_t return_data_size = <recived on runtime>;

// with my_double_func should be sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) ~ 5
size_t parameters_data_size = <recived on runtime>;

char * return_data = new char[return_data_size];
char * parameters_data = new char[parameters_data_size];

call_func(my_func, return_data_size, parameters_data_size, return_data, parameters_data); 

// so return_data now contains the value of double 
// and could be serialized for example
```

**It is prohibited to do the following! (as I cannot use exact type on compile time)**
`double value = ( (double(*)(int,char)) my_func)(a, b);`

P.S. Also it is acceptable if parameters are not in a single block of memory

Comment: You cannot call functions from a `void*` pointer,  you have to use an appropriate function pointer instead.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible with plain C++ under the constraints that you impose.

Comment: Where are these parameters coming from, and how are you going to check they match the function? This is going to crash horribly if anything is slightly off ...

Comment: _`// get from DLL for example`_ that's something you shouldn't need to care about in an application. The usual way is to link against either stubs for shared libs, or statically linked implementations. Configure your build system accordingly.

Comment: ok, but if I know the call convention e.g. __cdecl or __thiscall

Comment: So you just have a DLL, and no header and stubs for it? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I also don't see what knowing the call convention attributes should help in that case? These attributes are usually handled through `_dllimport` attributes in the header file.

Comment: Try adding a more complete example in the question. For example, `a` and `b` are mentioned just once, what are they?

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple different function signatures? In that case you need `if...else if...` ladder or something to select the correct signature.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to call a function at an address, first you need a function pointer with the correct type. Then assign the `void*` to that. Then convert/deserialize/memcpy your `parameters_data` to correct type of variables. Then call the function with the variables as parameters. Then convert/serialize/memcpy the return value into `return_data`.

Comment: It appears this is a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If not, you write assembly.

Comment: This is **Exactly** what I search for  https://linux.die.net/man/3/ffi_call:

«The ffi_call function provides a simple mechanism for invoking a function without requiring knowledge of the function's interface at compile time. fn is called with the values retrieved from the pointers in the avalue array. The return value from fn is placed in storage pointed to by rvalue. »

Comment: P.S. FFI library is also cross-platform and also works on windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is exactly what I searched for [linux.die.net/man/3/ffi_call](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ffi_call):

> The ffi_call function provides a simple mechanism for invoking a
> function without requiring knowledge of the function's interface at
> compile time. fn is called with the values retrieved from the pointers
> in the avalue array. The return value from fn is

FFI library is cross-platform.

Comment: Consider giving an example how exactly one what would use this function.